# How to force restart WBADMIN? Command line not responding

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, wbadmin

Just going through the backups this morning and I've noticed that the backups have failed for days now due to a backup job already running. Upon checking with the wbadmin get status command, the job looks to be stuck at 70%

I've ran the wbadmin stop job command, but it's been sat there for a couple of hours now and short of restarting the server I'm not sure what to do.

Does wbadmin operate under a task or service I can kill and restart? I don't want to restart the whole server just to reset the backups.

Thanks in advance for any advice,

D

Answer (score 1):

Windows Backup uses the Volume Shadow Copy Service on the source computer to perform the backup. Did you try restarting that service?

Comment: I didn't. I ended up throwing in the towel and restarting the entire server when we were quiet. There is another service called `Block Level Backup` Engine which is related, but kept falling over when I tried to restart it.